# How to round decimals to whole number depending on the value of decimals?

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding, floor, ceil

For example, if I am given a value 3.5, I wish to round it up to 4.

If I am given a value 3.4, it will be rounded down to 3.

I've tried the `ceil` and `floor` function. However, they are both only able to round up and down respectively.

This are what I've tried.

```
SELECT floor(avg(rate)) as average_age FROM review
```

gives 3 while

```
SELECT ceil(avg(rate)) as average_age FROM review
```

gives 4.

Comment: Try [`ROUND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)?

Comment: yea. that was right. I feel so dumb now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is ROUND() as given by eggyal.